# Vue.js 3 extension breaks while using "vue-cli-service build" due to unsafe-eval

Tags: vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension, vue-cli, vuejs3

I am developing a chrome extension using vue 3, vue-router and vuex based on [Kocal's project](https://github.com/Kocal/vue-web-extension-vue3) which uses `vue-cli` under the hood. I used whenever possible Single File Components with extensive use of vue bindings.
Everything works perfect on development mode but I recently tried to build the application for production and I encountered this **error** with partial rendering:

```js
chunk-vendors.f6de00a6.js:11 EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

After a few days of digging, my understanding is that either webpack or vue compiling system is messing with CSP by referring/injecting code through eval scripts. As I am fairly new to this, it's hard for me to read to distinguish what I can do.

I tried different approaches:

- defining `$vue` alias to a runtime only build in `vue.config.js` (supposedly removing unsafe eval by having code compiled before runtime but ending with a new error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` for `o=Object(n["withScopeId"])("data-v-21ae70c6");`)
- using `render()` function at root
- adding `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",` to `manifest.json`
- switching a component to `render()` to see if I have better chance with the partial rendering, but ending up with nothing being displayed although having console.log from render being executed.
- Adding a config to chainWebpack splitting manifest and inline manifest on vue.config

What puzzles me is that I can't shake off the `unsafe-eval`, with at best a partial display, at worst a blank page. Bindings seem to be shaken off regardless and using a router-link to change page will give a blank page.

Edit: After digging through compiled code from webpack and setting minimize opt to false, it seems the error comes from a vendor: [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Check your dependencies/packages, including those you wouldn't think they use `unsafe-eval`.

After digging into webpack internals and components building for vue3, here are the takeaways:

- using Single File Components and default vue-cli config is ok as it will indeed just need vue runtime, so no unsolicited `unsafe-eval`
- webpack config as below works:

```js
  module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          global: "window" // Placeholder for global used in any node_modules
        })
      ]
    },
    ...
  };
// Note that this plugin definition would break if you are using "unit-mocha" module for vue-cli
```

In the end, the issue was a dependency I was using for i18n `vue-i18n@next`, after removing it and switching to chrome's i18n way, it's now working.

Answer (score 1):

The `eval` is likely coming from Webpack, due to an issue with global scoping.
see link for more detail https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/globalthis

Could you try adding this configuration to `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    node: {
      global: false
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        global: "window"
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I saw the node: false config somewhere but haven't tried it. I added what you suggest to my vue.config.js, but I the same issue persists (partial rendering with eval errors)

Comment: I have been testing and testing again and the fact that I have at least partial rendering seems to indicate that webpack does at least some part of the compilation correctly. If I was to change vue$ alias to a runtime only build, I have indeed full blank screen. I think the issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: if runtime-only Vue is causing blank, it seems to indicate that the template is not being compiled, but from the repo  don't see a reason why that would be happening.

Comment: It is normal, vue-cli uses webpack to pre-compile .vue, and I was giving him the runtime only vue.js for this pre-compilation. It might not give much, but at least part of the .vue files are compiled.